# Elegant way to construct a matrix with symbolic entries

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I would like to construct a matrix $G$ composed of block matrices $G^{(i)}$ as defined entry-wise below stacked vertically as
$$G = \begin{bmatrix} G^{(1)} \\ G^{(2)} \\ \vdots \\ G^{(i)} \\ \vdots \\ G^{(n)} \end{bmatrix}$$
for some natural number $n$.

$G^{(i)}_{j,k}$ stands for the element of the $j$'th row and the $k$'th column of the $i$'th block matrix.
\begin{align}
G^{(i)}_{j,k} :=& \frac{t_{i+1}-t}{h_i}\delta_{k,i}+\frac{t-t_i}{h_i}\delta_{k,i+1} -\frac16(t-t_i)(t_{i+1}-t)\Big(1+\frac{t_{i+1}-t}{h_i}\Big)\delta_{k,n+i} \\
    &-\frac16(t-t_i)(t_{i+1}-t)\Big(1+\frac{t-t_i}{h_i}\Big)\delta_{k,n+i+1} \ \Bigg|_{t=t_{j,i}}
\end{align}
where $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, $j\in\{1,2,\cdots,m(j)\}$, $m(j)$ is a natural numbered function of $j$, and $k\in\{1,2,\cdots,2n-2\}$, $\delta_{i,j}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta),  and the vertical bar at the right end indicates $t$ is to be evaluated at $t_{j,t}$.

What is the most elegant and convenient way to do this?

Comment: ` t is to be evaluated at  t_j,t` - explain please. You have a mixture of $t,t_i,t_{i+1}$ in your problem, but is $t$ a function? And if so why does it take either 1 (i or i+1) or two arguments (j,i)?

Comment: @flinty: It just means substituting $t$ by $t_{j,i}$.

Comment: Use `SparseArray`. Or `DiagonalMatrix`.  What are the limits on `j` and `k`?  Are the G's square matrices? Can `n` be anything or is it related to the bounds on `i` and `j`?  More details would be helpful.

Comment: You have a $\delta_{k,i}$ and a $\delta_{n+k,n+i}$, but $\delta_{n+k,n+i}=\delta_{k,i}$, so these actually are part of the same matrix element.  I suspect that you meant something else, however, since you wrote them separately. Can you clarify?  I think editing your post with a small example output would be very helpful, with explicit (small) limits on j and j like 3 or something, i = 2 (so, two blocks), and n = something.  As it stands, $n$ actually doesn't do anything in this expression, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @march: You are absolutely right. I have edited my question. Please review. Thank you.

Comment: Please also provide some concrete example matrices for the first small $ n $s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have definitions already for `n`, single argument `t[x]`, and two-argument `t[x,y]`, then this is fairly straightforward:

```
g[i_, n_] := 
 Table[(t[i + 1] - t[j, i])/h[i] KroneckerDelta[k, 
     i] + (t[j, i] - t[i])/h[i] KroneckerDelta[k, i + 1] - 
   1/6 (t[j, i] - t[i]) (t[i + 1] - 
      t[j, i]) (1 + (t[i + 1] - t[j, i])/h[i]) KroneckerDelta[k, 
     n + i] - 
   1/6 (t[j, i] - t[i]) (t[i + 1] - 
      t[j, i]) (1 + ((t[j, i] - t[i])/h[i])) KroneckerDelta[k, 
     n + i + 1], {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 2*n-2}]

result = With[{n = 4}, Join @@ Array[g[#, n] &, n]]
result // Dimensions (*expected {12,3}*)
result // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Is there a command to show the final explicit matrix form without the explicit KroneckerDelta function?

Comment: @Hans can you explain what you're after? MatrixForm is just a presentational thing - you shouldn't use it in computations.

Comment: Your solution is good. I understand I can use it for computation. I am wondering  if there is a command to see the matrix in the explicit more conventional form as a sanity check.

Comment: Yes that's what the `//MatrixForm` is for. It just looks weird because the expressions in the matrix are very wide.

Comment: Nice. I have just edited my question and corrected the indexing of the elements. It would be great if you can edit your answer accordingly. Thank you very much, flinty.

Comment: I have updated it. Note that with your edits if I choose an n beyond n=3 the last matrix blocks are just zero.

Comment: +1. Thank you. I have made another small edit to the question adding the indexing for $j$. I suppose the upper limit of $k$ can be a variable so that '{k, 1, 2*n-2}', instead of a hard coded number. Is that right?

Comment: @Hans you just need to change the limits then: `{j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}` change to `{j, 1, m[n]}, {k, 1, 2*n-2}` if you want that, but you must have the function `m[n_]:=...` defined somewhere - an abstract m[n] is impossible here.

Comment: Understood. I edited your answer to reflect the change. One more question: Which part of 'Join @@ Array[g[#, n] &, n]]' indicates the stacking is vertical rather than horizontal?

Comment: @Hans `Array[g[#, n] &, n]` generates a list of `{g[1,n],g[2,n],g[3,n],..., g[n,n]}` and `@@` splices this list into a sequence of arguments for `Join` , so `Join[g[1,n],g[2,n],g[3,n]...]`. This is stacking them 'vertically' though Mathematica isn't like matlab; it works on lists, so it doesn't have a notion of vertical/horizontal, just lists and list nesting. If you wanted them horizontal you would use `Join[g[1,n],g[2,n],g[3,n]....,{2}]` with a level spec `{2}` at the end.

Comment: OK. Does the format 'g[#,m] &, n]' mean running variable '#' from $1$ to $n$?

Comment: @Hans Yes with Array, take a look at this example from the documentation https://wolfram.com/xid/02cre-ypy

Answer (score 2):

Is this a formula with the Einstein sum convention. If so then the summation over two same indices has to be carried through.

```
g[i_, j_, k_, n_] := 
 Sum[(t[i + 1] - t[j, i])/h[ii] KroneckerDelta[k, 
     ii] + (t[j, i] - t[ii])/h[ii] KroneckerDelta[k, ii + 1] - 
   1/6 (t[j, i] - t[ii]) (t[ii + 1] - 
      t[j, i]) (1 + (t[ii + 1] - t[j, i])/h[ii]) KroneckerDelta[n + k,
      n + ii] - 
   1/6 (t[j, i] - t[ii]) (t[ii + 1] - 
      t[j, i]) (1 + ((t[j, i] - t[ii])/h[ii])) KroneckerDelta[n + k, 
     n + ii + 1], {ii, 1, 3}]
```

---

```
g[1, j, k, n]
```

---

```
(KroneckerDelta[1, k] (t[2] - t[j, 1]))/h[1] + (
 KroneckerDelta[2, k] (t[2] - t[j, 1]))/h[2] + (
 KroneckerDelta[3, k] (t[2] - t[j, 1]))/h[3] + (
 KroneckerDelta[2, k] (-t[1] + t[j, 1]))/h[1] - 
 1/6 KroneckerDelta[1 + n, 
   k + n] (1 + (t[2] - t[j, 1])/h[1]) (t[2] - t[j, 1]) (-t[1] + 
    t[j, 1]) + (KroneckerDelta[3, k] (-t[2] + t[j, 1]))/h[2] - 
 1/6 KroneckerDelta[2 + n, 
   k + n] (1 + (t[3] - t[j, 1])/h[2]) (t[3] - t[j, 1]) (-t[2] + 
    t[j, 1]) + (KroneckerDelta[4, k] (-t[3] + t[j, 1]))/h[3] - 
 1/6 KroneckerDelta[3 + n, 
   k + n] (1 + (t[4] - t[j, 1])/h[3]) (t[4] - t[j, 1]) (-t[3] + 
    t[j, 1]) - 
 1/6 KroneckerDelta[2 + n, 
   k + n] (t[2] - t[j, 1]) (-t[1] + t[j, 1]) (1 + (-t[1] + t[j, 1])/
    h[1]) - 1/
  6 KroneckerDelta[3 + n, 
   k + n] (t[3] - t[j, 1]) (-t[2] + t[j, 1]) (1 + (-t[2] + t[j, 1])/
    h[2]) - 1/
  6 KroneckerDelta[4 + n, 
   k + n] (t[4] - t[j, 1]) (-t[3] + t[j, 1]) (1 + (-t[3] + t[j, 1])/
    h[3])
```

The interpretation distinguishes between the indices i of the Einstein summation and the indices i from the discretization of time i in t_ij.

Example for displaying this as a matrix is

```
Table[h[i, j, k, n], {i, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

This is much to lengthy for g.

Comment: Actually, there is no summation over 'ii' here. 'ii' should be the index of the block matrix.